# Train accuracy is great, but test accuracy is bad

Tags: keras

I used `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` to train and test my model.
When it is training, the accuracy was up to 90%.
But when I test my model, the accuracy was just the average(50%).

This is how I use `ImageDataGenerator`:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path + '\\train', target_size=(224, 224),
                                     classes=['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA'],
                                     batch_size=10)

test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path + '\\test', target_size=(224, 224),
                                    classes=['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA'],
                                    batch_size=10)
```

This is how I train and test my model:

```
model.fit_generator(train_data, steps_per_epoch=32, epochs=100)

test_info = model.evaluate_generator(test_data, steps=10)

print(test_info)
```

I tried to replace `test_data` with `train_data` when test the model. 
But the result was identical.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your model is over fitting on the training data. You can try some methods to prevent it like:

- early stopping
- Regularization( dropout, L1/L2 regularization)
- cross-validation
- Increasing dataset(if possible)
- Reduce architecture complexity

Comment: I used early stopping to avoid overfitting, It's effective. Thank you!